# What is the best algorithm to solve my maze?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, maze

I am trying to solve a map solving problem which using simple AI.

We are given 3 functions to work with:

- move: moves 1 tile forward depending on the orientation (Up, Down, Left, Right) of the adventurer (the agent).
- rotate: rotates the adventurer and changes the orientation 90 degrees clockwise.
- scan: returns the nearest object to the adventurer with the regards to the orientation. It also scans up to the edge of the map and will only return empty if no object has been found.

There are 4 types of result of the scan.

- princess: this is the goal of the adventurer to reach.
- spike: the adventurer must avoid the spikes or else it's game over.
- tower: this tells the adventurer that the princess is along the axis of the tower (a spike cant be between a princess and a tower)
- empty: no object is within the axis of the scan.

The user does not know the content of the map and will start with 0 knowledge and is supposed to find the most efficient way to reach the princess.

What approach can I possibly use to solve this problem given that the locations of the spike, princess, and the tower are randomly generated?

Here is an example map:

[image: Red - Adventurer, Pink - Princess, Black - Spike]

Red - Adventurer, Pink - Princess, Black - Spike

Comment: Does scan also return the distance?

Comment: I don't understand what tower is/means.

Comment: @Surt no, it will only return the nearest object found.

Comment: @trincot the tower works like an object which notifies the agent that the princess is within the axis of the tower. for example, if the tower is at (1,0), then the princess must be between (2,0) up to (n,0) (n depending on the size of the map)

Comment: You can use a modified Depth First Search for example. Get all agent's neighbors by doing scan, rotate 4 times. If one of the neighbors is a : Prince - goal reached. Tower - add to stack and ignore others. Other wise put all neighbors accept spikes in stack.

Comment: If you don't get the distance and only see spike or edge in all 4 directions, there is no guarantee you can avoid walking into a spike.

Comment: @trincot I thought that this would be the case but our professor for this subject kept on insisting that theres a possible solution. thank you anyway!

Comment: Either something is missing in the info you provided or your professor is wrong. In the example you have given there is no reason why you would not immediately jump of the edge of the maze by going Up (for instance), as we can surely imagine mazes where it is *necessary* to walk towards an edge in order to find the path, yet you have no info whether you are next to the edge. Similarly there is no reason why you would not walk to the right until you bump into the spike. We can see the solution is to go down a few times and the right, but there is no info available to give you that clue.

Comment: How many tries on each map are you allowed?

Comment: [Red - Adventurer, Pink - Princess, Black - Spike] somehow got edited out

Answer (score 0):

I will take a shot at this, under the assumption

- that when we hit a spike we can start over on the same map.
- we know the size of the map
- we know where on the map we start

Idea

- Use BFS to find square with unknown content, move there, scan
- Repeat until princess or tower found
- move to tower or princess
- if spike hit restart with the now known squares.

More detailed pseudo code

```
make a map of 0..size+1 with all squares marked unknown
make start empty 
mark all edge squares as edges.

start:
Repeat
  Find nearest square where there is a direction with an unknown as nearest none empty
  Move to that square
  if step on spike 
    mark square as spike
    goto start:  // replace with return/throw/whatever

  While direction with an unknown as nearest none empty
    turn if needed
    scan in that direction
    mark the first unknown in that direction with maybe result of scan
    call CheckScan


CheckScan:
  if maybe empty found
    mark all squares in that direction empty until edge.
  if maybe princess is found 
    move in that direction repeatedly, finish when reached

  if maybe tower is found 
    move in that direction until reached
    mark it tower

  if tower is found 
    for each direction 
      if direction with an unknown as nearest none empty
        scan
      if maybe princess is found 
        move in that direction repeatedly, finish when reached
      turn 90
```

There will definitively be bugs and possible improvements possible.